# Deleting a connection property with nmcli

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I am trying to use nmcli to edit an existing connection and I would like to remove completely some properties (as opposed to just modifying their value).

Specifically the properties are `wifi-sec.key-mgmt` and `wifi-sec.psk` and the use case is because the network has been switched to open mode from wpa-psk mode.

I can't seem to find a way to delete these properties, and the nmcli help seems to point to the command `nmcli connection modify` but it doesn't seem to have the ability to delete entire properties, just delete some items in multi-value properties, which is not the case for the ones I want.

```
Usage: nmcli connection modify { ARGUMENTS | help }

ARGUMENTS := [id | uuid | path] <ID> ([+|-]<setting>.<property> <value>)+

Modify one or more properties of the connection profile.
The profile is identified by its name, UUID or D-Bus path. For multi-valued
properties you can use optional '+' or '-' prefix to the property name.
The '+' sign allows appending items instead of overwriting the whole value.
The '-' sign allows removing selected items instead of the whole value.
```

Is there any way to completely remove a property via nmcli or do I have to delete the whole connection and then re-create it without these properties ?

Note that this needs to be invoked from another program, so interactive mode commands are not suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the property is not a flag or container-type (if it is, use the `nmcli c modify conid -setting.property value` syntax you describe) then the [nmcli man page](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html) specifies to set the property value to an empty string to reset it to defaults:

```bsh
nmcli con modify id setting.property ""
```

You can also use the 'remove' keyword to unset a whole setting section on the connection instead of a specific property via:

```bsh
nmcli con modify [--temporary] [id | uuid | path] ID remove setting
```

Answer (score 0):

Information from [nmcli manual](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html):

1. First you need to identify the connection you want to edit with the following command:

   `nmcli connection show`
2. Then, assuming you have a connection named 'Ethernet' (used here just as an example) use this command:

   `nmcli connection edit Ethernet`

It starts the `===| nmcli interactive connection editor |===`, which can remove properties of a connection.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this does not work for me because nmcli is invoked by another program, thus I can't go into interactive mode. I updated the original question.